# Conditional Increment and Decrement Operator in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello everyone i need one help on js script, i written a script for form input, there is two condition one condition take max value 1(one) and other condition take max value 5(two) in same form, those value was generating from one script, here is my script.Also added the PDF screen shot, i want to make this form like this : https://prnt.sc/vuscqy
but now i getting this : https://prnt.sc/vusd0t
Can anyone help me on this, i added full code into the below.

```
  <style type="text/css">* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
  input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
  input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  margin: 0;
  }
  input[type="checkbox"] {
  -webkit-appearance: checkbox !important;
  margin: 2px 0px 0px !important;
  }

  /* Firefox */
  input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance:textfield;
  }
  .font-color{
  color: #333333 !important;
  }
  .navbar-brand-wrapper a img {
   width: 140px;
   height: 35px;
   margin-top: 12px;
   }
   .field-size-top-large {
   border: 2px solid rgb(219, 222, 226) !important;
   box-shadow: none !important;
   border-radius: 5px !important;
   }
   option, select {
   font-family:karbon;
   }
   .limi t{    
   color:red !important;    
   font-family: Karbon;    
   font-size: 1.5rem;    
   display: none;
   text-align:right;
  }
  .minus_button {    
  border: 2px solid #DBDEE2;   
  text-align: center;    
  cursor: pointer;    
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;    
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;    
  border-top-right-radius: 0 !important;    
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0 !important;    
  background: #F0F0F0;    
  color:#9E9E9E;    
  display: inline-block;    
  vertical-align: middle;    
  margin:0;    
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  }
 .plus_button {    
  border: 2px solid #DBDEE2;    
  text-align: center;    
  cursor: pointer;    
  display: inline-block;    
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;        border-top-left-radius: 0 
  !important;    border-bottom-left-radius: 0 !important;    background: #F0F0F0;    color:#9E9E9E;    
   vertical-align: middle;    margin-bottom: 0 !important;}.inputfield{text-align: center 
  !important;border: 2px solid #DBDEE2 !important;box-shadow: none !important;border-radius: 0 
  !important;border-left:none !important;border-right: none !important;font-size: 2rem 
  !important;width:40px !important;display: inline-block !important;height: 30px !important;padding:0 
  !important;margin:0 !important;vertical-align: middle !important;}.white- 
  bg{background:white;padding:20px;}

  * {
  font-family: "Karbon";
  }

  @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
 .navbar-brand-wrapper a img {
  width: 140px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  }
  .navbar-brand-wrapper .navbar-brand {
  left: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  }
  }
  </style>
  <div class="bs-grid container-fluid headline" id="bs-grid-edit-body-und-0-value-3">
  <div class="row row-1 row-first row-last">
    <div class="col col-first -last col-last col-md-12">
        <div class="content">
            <h2 class="font-color">
                Supporting resources
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div>
&nbsp;
</div>
 <div class="bs-grid container-fluid white-bg" id="bs-grid-edit-body-und-0-value-0">
<h3 class="font-color">
    Request print materials
</h3>
<p>
    Thank you for your interest. Below you will find a list of print materials which are available on request.
</p>
<p>
    Please select which print materials you wish to receive, by clicking on the + or - sign next to the description.
</p>
<p>
    You will receive an email with an overview of your requested materials and quantities.
</p>
<form action="https://s1988571858.t.eloqua.com/e/f2" class="elq-form" id="form2564" method="post" name="K_Darzalex_Order_Resources_Form-637393800901096797" onsubmit="return handleFormSubmit(this)">
    <input name="elqFormName" type="hidden" value="K_Darzalex_Order_Resources_Form-637393800901096797" /> <input name="elqSiteId" type="hidden" value="1988571858" /> <input name="elqCampaignId" type="hidden" />
    <div class="bs-grid container-fluid" id="bs-grid-edit-body-und-0-value-0">
        <div class="row row-1 row-first row-last">
            <div class="col col-first col-md-6">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="bestel-details" style="border: 2px solid #F3F6F8;padding:20px;margin-bottom: 20px;">
                        <h3 style="margin-top:0;">
                            <span style="font-size:18px;">List of print materials which<br />Personal information are available to request</span>
                        </h3>
                        <h3 style="margin-top:0;">
                            <span style="font-size:16px;">Print materials for Healthcare Professionals</span>
                        </h3>
                        <div class="bs-grid container-fluid" id="bs-grid-edit-body-und-0-value-2">
                            <div class="row row-1 row-first">
                                <div class="col col-first col-md-9">
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <p id="active-material" style="font-family: Karbon;">
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col col-last col-md-3">
                                    <div class="content">
                                        <p class="aantal" style="text-align: right;">
                                            <input class="minus_button" data-type="minus" type="Button" value="-" /><input class="field-size-top-large inputfield aantal-exemplaren" id="active-material-input-name" max="1" min="0" name="" type="number" value="0" /><input class="plus_button" data-type="plus" type="Button" value="+" />
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="border: 2px solid #F3F6F8;padding:20px;margin-bottom: 20px;">
                        <h3 style="margin-top:0;">
                            <span class="font-color" style="font-size:16px;">Print materials for patients</span>
                        </h3>
                        <div id="remainingMaterials">
                            <div class="bs-grid container-fluid" id="bs-grid-edit-body-und-0-value-1">
                                <div class="row row-1 row-first">
                                    <div class="col col-first col-md-9">
                                        <div class="content">
                                            <p id="materialName">
                                                &nbsp;
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col col-last col-md-3">
                                        <div class="content">
                                            <p class="aantal" style="text-align: right;">
                                                <input class="minus_button" data-type="minus" type="button" value="-" /><input class="field-size-top-large inputfield aantal-exemplaren" max="5" min="0" name="" type="number" value="0" /><input class="plus_button" data-type="plus" type="button" value="+" />
                                            </p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-last col-md-6">
                <div class="content">
                    <div style="border: 2px solid #F3F6F8;padding:20px;margin-bottom: 15px;">
                        <h3 style="margin-top:0;">
                            <span class="font-color" style="font-size:16px;">Personal information</span>
                        </h3>
                        <p>
                            <label class="label-position top" for="fe25762">First name:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><input class="field-size-top-large" id="fe25762" name="firstName" required="required" type="text" value="" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label class="label-position top" for="fe25763">Last name:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><input class="field-size-top-large" id="fe25763" name="lastName" required="required" type="text" value="" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label class="label-position top" for="fe25764">Email Address:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><input class="field-size-top-large" id="fe25764" name="emailAddress" required="required" type="email" value="" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label class="label-position top" for="fe25765">Delivery Address:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><input class="field-size-top-large" id="fe25765" name="deliveryAddress" required="required" type="text" value="" />
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label class="label-position top" for="fe25782">Postcode:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label><input class="field-size-top-large" id="fe25782" name="passCode" required="required" type="text" value="" />
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row row-1 row-first row-last">
                        <div class="col col-first col-lg-1">
                            <div class="content">
                                <p>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col col-lg-10">
                            <div class="content">
                                <p>
                                    Any personal information you provide to Janssen in this form will only be used for the purposes of sending you the requested print material. For further details, please see our privacy policy: <a class="ext" href="http://Any personal information you provide to Janssen in this form will only be used for the purposes of sending you the requested print material. For further details, please see our privacy policy: www.janssenmedicalcloud.co.uk/privacy-policy">www.janssenmedicalcloud.co.uk/privacy-policy<span class="ext"><span class="element-invisible"> (link is external)</span></span></a>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col col-last col-lg-1">
                            <div class="content">
                                <p>
                                    &nbsp;
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <p>
                        <input class="btn btn-default" id="fe25781" type="submit" value="Submit" />
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<p>
 <span style="font-size:12px;">CP-191061 | December 2020</span>
 </p><script type="text/javascript" 
 src="https://img03.en25.com/i/livevalidation_standalone.compressed.js">
</script><script>
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
if (!url) url = window.location.href;
name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
    results = regex.exec(url);
if (!results) return null;
if (!results[2]) return '';
return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' ').replace(/,/g, ''));
}  

var items = [
{ title: "Dosing card", name: "dosing-card"},
{ title: "Dosing poster", name: "dosingPoster"},
{ title: "Homecare guide for Healthcare Professionals", name: "homecare-guide-for-professional"},
{ title: "myStelara® guide for patients", name: "myStelara"},
{ title: "Homecare guide for patients", name: "homecare-guide-for-patient"},
{ title: "Stelara® pocket guide for patients", name: "stelaraPocket"},
];


function handleIncrDecrButton(){
var type = jQuery(this).data("type");
var input = jQuery(this).parent().find("[type='number']");

var max = parseInt(jQuery(input).attr("max")) || 5;
var min = parseInt(jQuery(input).attr("min")) || 0;

var update = type === "minus" ? -1 : 1;
var value = parseInt(jQuery(input).val());
var incr = value + update;

if (incr < min || incr > max) {
  return;
}

jQuery(input).val(incr);
}

function renderRemainder() {
var remainingMaterials = jQuery("#remainingMaterials");
var order = getParameterByName("item");
var field = remainingMaterials.children().first().clone();
remainingMaterials.html("");
var filtered = order ? items.filter(function(item){ return item.name !== order }) : items;

filtered.forEach(function(item){
field = field.clone();
var title = item.title;
var name = item.name;
field.find("#materialName").html(title);
field.find("[type='number']").attr("name", name);
remainingMaterials.append(field);
});
}

function setActiveMaterial() {
var material = jQuery(".bestel-details");
var order = getParameterByName("item");
var item = items.filter(function(item){
  return item.name === order;
})[0];

if (item) {
  material.find("[type='button']").on("click", handleIncrDecrButton);
  material.find("#active-material").html(item.title);
  material.find("[type='number']").attr("name", item.name);
  } else {
  jQuery(".bestel-details").remove();
   }
  }

  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var el = jQuery('.aantal-exemplaren');
  var paramSenderMail = getParameterByName('senderMail') || "";
  var remainingMaterials = jQuery("#remainingMaterials");
  var order = getParameterByName("order", location.href);

   document.getElementById('senderMail').value = paramSenderMail;
   jQuery(".succes-url").val(successUrl);

   remainingMaterials.on("click", "[type='button']", handleIncrDecrButton);

   setActiveMaterial();
   renderRemainder();

   var formId = "#" + jQuery("body") .find(".elq-form").attr("id");
   var baseUrl = location.protocol + "//" + location.host + location.pathname;
    var refUrl = "/thank-you";

   var $emailAddress = jQuery("[name='emailAdress']");
   var $permissionCheckbox = jQuery("[name='permissionField']");
   var $lastName = jQuery("[name='lastName']");
   var $codsId = jQuery("#codsid");
   var $form = jQuery(formId);
   var $succesUrl = jQuery("#successUrl");

   $permissionCheckbox.change(function() {
   $codsId.val(""); // Clear Prev CodsID
   jQuery(this).attr("checked", jQuery(this).is(":checked"));
   codsIdLookup();
   });

   $emailAddress.on("input", handleCodsIdLookup);
   $lastName.on("input", handleCodsIdLookup);
   $form.on("submit", function(event) {
    return true;
   });

    function setElqContent() {
   var iconnectURL = "https://iconnect-emea.my.salesforce.com/_ui/search/ui/UnifiedSearchResults? 
   str=";
    var id = GetElqContentPersonalizationValue("C_CODS_Id1") || $lastName.val();
    $codsId.val(id && iconnectURL + id);
   }

   function codsIdLookup() {
   var emailAddress = $emailAddress.val();
   if (emailAddress) {
  _elqQ.push(["elqDataLookup", escape("df5c0f6c54f44773bb77820bd3c845c8"), "<C_EmailAddress>" + 
   emailAddress + "</" + "C_EmailAddress>"]);
   }
   }

  function handleCodsIdLookup() {
   if ($permissionCheckbox.is(":checked")) {
  codsIdLookup();
  }
  }

   window.SetElqContent = setElqContent;
  $succesUrl.val(baseUrl + refUrl);
   });
   function handleFormSubmit(ele) {
   var submitButton = ele.querySelector('input[type=submit]');
   var spinner = document.createElement('span');
   spinner.setAttribute('class', 'loader');
   submitButton.setAttribute('disabled', true);
   submitButton.style.cursor = 'wait';
   submitButton.parentNode.appendChild(spinner);
    return true;
   }
 function resetSubmitButton(e){
var submitButtons = e.target.form.getElementsByClassName('submit-button');
for(var i=0;i<submitButtons.length;i++){
  submitButtons[i].disabled = false;
}
}
function addChangeHandler(elements){
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
  elements[i].addEventListener('change', resetSubmitButton);
}
}
var form = document.getElementById('form2541');
addChangeHandler(form.getElementsByTagName('input'));
addChangeHandler(form.getElementsByTagName('select'));
addChangeHandler(form.getElementsByTagName('textarea'));
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('#form2541 input[data-subscription]');
if (nodes) {
for (var i = 0, len = nodes.length; i < len; i++) {
  var status = nodes[i].dataset ? nodes[i].dataset.subscription : nodes[i].getAttribute('data- 
 subscription');
  if(status ==='true') {
    nodes[i].checked = true;
  }
 }
  };
 var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('#form2541 select[data-value]');
 if (nodes) {
 for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
  var node = nodes[i];
  var selectedValue = node.dataset ? node.dataset.value : node.getAttribute('data-value');
  if (selectedValue) {
    for (var j = 0; j < node.options.length; j++) {
      if(node.options[j].value === selectedValue) {
        node.options[j].selected = 'selected';
        break;
      }
    }
   }
 }
 }
   this.getParentElement = function(list) {
      return list[list.length-1].parentElement};
    var dom0 = document.querySelector('#form2541 #fe25535');
    var fe25535 = new LiveValidation(dom0, {
      validMessage: "", onlyOnBlur: false, wait: 300}
                                    );
    var dom1 = document.querySelector('#form2541 #fe25536');
    var fe25536 = new LiveValidation(dom1, {
      validMessage: "", onlyOnBlur: false, wait: 300}
                                    );
    fe25536.add(Validate.Presence, {
      failureMessage:"This field is required"}
               );
    fe25536.add(Validate.Length, {
      tooShortMessage:"Invalid length for field value", tooLongMessage: "Invalid length for field 
    value",  minimum: 0, maximum: 35}
               );
    var dom2 = document.querySelector('#form2541 #fe25537');
    var fe25537 = new LiveValidation(dom2, {
      validMessage: "", onlyOnBlur: false, wait: 300}
                                    );
    fe25537.add(Validate.Presence, {
      failureMessage:"This field is required"}
               );
    fe25537.add(Validate.Length, {
      tooShortMessage:"Invalid length for field value", tooLongMessage: "Invalid length for field 
    value",  minimum: 0, maximum: 35}
               );
    var dom3 = document.querySelector('#form2541 #fe25538');
    var fe25538 = new LiveValidation(dom3, {
      validMessage: "", onlyOnBlur: false, wait: 300}
                                    );
    fe25538.add(Validate.Format, {
      pattern: /(^[A-Z0-9!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`\{\|\}~][A-Z0-9!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`\{\|\}~\.] 
     {0,62}@(([A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?)(\.[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?)+)$)/i, 
     failureMessage: "A valid email address is required"}
               );
    fe25538.add(Validate.Format, {
      pattern: /\.\.|\.@/i, failureMessage: "A valid email address is required", negate: "true"}
               );
    fe25538.add(Validate.Presence, {
      failureMessage:"This field is required"}
               );
    var dom4 = document.querySelector('#form2541 #fe25539');
    var fe25539 = new LiveValidation(dom4, {
      validMessage: "", onlyOnBlur: false, wait: 300}
                                    );
    fe25539.add(Validate.Presence, {
      failureMessage:"This field is required"}
               );
    fe25539.add(Validate.Length, {
      tooShortMessage:"Invalid length for field value", tooLongMessage: "Invalid length for field 
     value",  minimum: 0, maximum: 35}
               );
    var dom5 = document.querySelector('#form2541 #fe25541');
    var fe25541 = new LiveValidation(dom5, {
      validMessage: "", onlyOnBlur: false, wait: 300}
                                    );
    var dom6 = document.querySelector('#form2541 #fe25542');
    var fe25542 = new LiveValidation(dom6, {
      validMessage: "", onlyOnBlur: false, wait: 300}
                                    );
    var dom7 = document.querySelector('#form2541 #fe25543');
    var fe25543 = new LiveValidation(dom7, {
      validMessage: "", onlyOnBlur: false, wait: 300}
                                    );
    var dom8 = document.querySelector('#form2541 #fe25544');
    var fe25544 = new LiveValidation(dom8, {
      validMessage: "", onlyOnBlur: false, wait: 300}
                                    );
    var dom9 = document.querySelector('#form2541 #fe25545');
    var fe25545 = new LiveValidation(dom9, {
      validMessage: "", onlyOnBlur: false, wait: 300}
                                    );
    var dom10 = document.querySelector('#form2541 #fe25546');
    var fe25546 = new LiveValidation(dom10, {
      validMessage: "", onlyOnBlur: false, wait: 300}
                                    );
    var dom11 = document.querySelector('#form2541 #fe25562');
    var fe25562 = new LiveValidation(dom11, {
      validMessage: "", onlyOnBlur: false, wait: 300}
                                    );
    fe25562.add(Validate.Custom, {
      against: function(value) {
        return !value.match(/(telnet|ftp|https?):\/\/(?:[a-z0-9][a-z0-9-]{0,61}[a-z0-9]\.|[a-z0-9]\.)+[a-z]{2,63}/i);
      }
      , failureMessage: "Value must not contain any URL's"}
               );
    fe25562.add(Validate.Custom, {
      against: function(value) {
        return !value.match(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig);
      }
      , failureMessage: "Value must not contain any HTML"}
               );
  </script>
```

Comment: you dont explain what is your problem?

Comment: i added screen shot into the post , my values are not fetched from the script and not showing into the page as well , how to write two multiple condition for (1 and 5) as per screen name : form like this @Frenchy